Does installing a custom ROM solve spyware problems on a Xiaomi?
I have done extensive research into the world of ROMs, but could not find the answer to the question: whether a device contains spyware on the firmware level.
I want to know whether unlocking the bootloader, and installing a custom de-googled ROM solves the problem of spyware on a Xiaomi phone.
I'd like to point the question towards Xiaomi, but in general, it would be nice to hear something on the overarching issue of: does installing a custom ROM on a mobile device solve spyware problems?

Which ROM you use is simply a question of trust. Do you trust the custom ROM developer more than Xiaomi or not.

And you're starting with a wrong, uninformed, and potentially xenophobic, assumption.

@Robert that is still taking it higher to the OS level. There's a lot of information on that, but nothing I could find on firmware.

@ChanganAuto the assumption would be that firmware contains spyware? You're probably right that I am uninformed. The point of this post was to get informed, so I would appreciate it if you told me what should change in my thinking? Point me in the right direction.

Yes, you assume you have a problem - spyware - without any understanding of what that is and singling out a specific brand.

Spyware is malicious software that enters a user’s computer, gathers data from the device and user, and sends it to third parties without their consent. Neither Google Services nor any other part of the custom Android Xiaomi provides is spyware. Both Google and Xiaomi collect data from users but always with their explicit consent. This happens with ALL phones out there. You'd need Chinese ROMs to avoid Google but then the tradeoff is having similar native services instead that aren't at all useful outside China.

@ChanganAuto I assume Kamil has the following article about Mi browser in mind when talking ab out Xiaomi and Spyware: https://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2020/04/30/exclusive-warning-over-chinese-mobile-giant-xiaomi-recording-millions-of-peoples-private-web-and-phone-use/

@Robert What that arguably FUD article mentions is not spyware. It's no different than so many other apps that send data to 3rd party companies for the purpose of targeted adds. Most send them to Amazon. Irrespective of the destination, the users explicitly consent to it the first time they open the app, also included in the ToS, etc. And, like any legit app, adds can be disabled in settings, anonymous mode can be enabled by default, and privacy settings activated in order to avoid data being sent to whoever it is sent.

@Robert Also it happens only in the cheaper sub-brands, not the main one, precisely because those sub-brands are partially "add-sponsored".

@ChanganAuto thanks for the clarification. What I probably meant by spyware, is any sort of backdoor that can be accessed without my knowledge and cause data leakage without consent.
I have been informed that Chinese companies are notorious for spying, so was unsure if simply installing a ROM solves the problem. You're mostly right about the fact that users explicitly consent to being spied on, but I don't believe that tech giants don't abuse harvested data. Getting a de-googled ROM that is not Chinese certainly is possible, by the way: https://itsfoss.com/android-distributions-roms/.

I have been informed that Chinese companies are notorious for spying You've been misinformed, they're the one doing the least. And, again, as long as you're informed of and consent to giving some of your personal data that's anything but spyware. You're also conflating "Google" with spyware just because they actively mine your data like no other which is ridiculous. It's always a trade-off between user's privacy and convenience, you can't have both. (...)

(...)  And yes, of course you can have Android without Google services but those ROMs aren't official and then you have to trust the not so transparent actors that make them. The only way to have official ROMs for your Xiaomi device without Google is actually installing the ones made for China.

FS0C131Y

@ChanganAuto then you have to trust the not so transparent actors that make them Aren't most custom ROMs free and open-source? Doesn't installing builds of well-known ROMs that are at least open-source resolve the issue of trust and transparency?

Not really. Even if they're completely open-source you'd need to be an expert to audit it. If you were you obviously wouldn't be here asking. But thi isn't a forum, comments aren't for discussions and you question is off-topic anywaty.
